# SUTSE DLM on daily mean water & air temperature TS

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, interpolation, dlm

I have two time series: (1) daily mean water temperature from 1988 to 2014 and (2) daily mean air temperature from 1968 to 2010. The water temperature time series has missing data, occurring on individual days and for periods of consecutive days (e.g., data for all of 1993 is missing). The air temperature data has data missing from 1990-02-01 - 1991-09-30. The data are plotted below:

[image: Water temperatures. Red bands indicate missing data. Smooth is annual GAM.]

[image: Airtemperatures. Red bands indicate missing data. Smooth is annual GAM.]

I want to use the air temperature series to inform missing values in the water temperature series.

From my understanding, this could be achieved using a state-space or Dynamic Linear model (DLM). I’m imagining a Seemingly Unrelated Time Series Equations (SUTSE) DLM in which both temperature series follow a stochastic linear trend and annual seasonal component.

So far (I’m only learning DLM), I have managed to fit a simple 2nd order stochastic linear trend SUTSE DLM to the water and air time series (both reduced to the same period 1986-08-19 to 2010-04-15) as follows (I’m afraid a data-sharing agreement forbids me to provide the data):

```
# the 'base' univariate model
uni <- dlmModPoly()

# to get the matrices of the correct dim
temps_mod <- uni %+% uni 

## now redefine matrices to keep levels together and slopes together
FF(temps_mod) <- FF(uni) %x% diag(2)
GG(temps_mod) <- GG(uni) %x% diag(2)
W(temps_mod)[] <- 0 # 'clean' the system variance

## define a build function for MLE
buildSUTSE <- function(psi) {
  U <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  U[upper.tri(U)] <- psi[1:2]
  diag(U) <- exp(0.5 * psi[3:4])
  W(temps_mod)[3:4, 3:4] <- crossprod(U)
  diag(V(temps_mod)) <- exp(0.5 * psi[5:6])
  temps_mod
}

## estimation
temps_est <- dlmMLE(temps, rep(-2, 9), buildSUTSE,
                 control = list(maxit = 500)) ## few iters for test

## check convergence
print(temps_est$conv)

## set up fitted model
temps_mod <- buildSUTSE(temps_est$par)

## look at the estimated variance / covariance matrices
print(W(temps_mod)[2:3, 2:3])
print(cov2cor(W(temps_mod)[2:3, 2:3])) # slopes
print(sqrt(diag(V(temps_mod)))) # observation standard deviations

## smooths
tempsSmooth <- dlmSmooth(temps, temps_mod)
```

which results in the following fits:

[image: SUTSE DLM linear stochastic trend fits]

While it is encouraging to see that the fitting has worked, the 1993 water temperature estimates look poor / too low relative to the surrounding values.
Here are my questions:

- Am I taking the right approach, or is there a better / simpler way to estimate missing water temperature data from air temperature?
- How do I extend the above code to include a seasonal trend, with (presumably) a frequency of 365 (even though leap years are present)? Should I be considering trigonometric functions, e.g., dlmModTrig?
- Has anyone seen this attempted before, and if so, where can I read about it (preferably with an R example)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Although I do not have specific advice, I think you might be expecting too much of this approach. In effect you are regressing air on water and water on air (and various lags thereof), so you should expect *regression to the mean* to occur for your estimates. That would fully account for the apparent shrinkage of the imputed values (of air in 1990 and water in 1993 and elsewhen) back towards a mean value and for their relatively low variances. If you want realistic-looking imputations you will need to make *predictions* using simulations.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. It does indeed look like this method produces estimates regressed towards a mean and that's not what I want. Can you give me any pointers on reading about using simulations to make realistic predictions? I have fitted deterministic trigonometric models to the water temperature data previously but I would like to use the air temperature data to help fill the gaps.